# Rollback to old version of Postgres after Pg_Upgrade

Tags: database, postgresql, performance, postgresql-9.4, postgresql-9.6

I ran pg_upgrade to upgrade my 9.4 schema to 9.6, and now we're seeing a ton of performance issues. Worst case scenario, if we want to roll back, is there a way to roll back the 9.6 schema to 9.4?

I still have the 9.4 schema in the old data dir, but it's a day old at this point, and already "stale" by our application's standards.

Comment: Did you run vacuum analyze after upgrading?

Comment: @Jeremy, I did not.

Comment: You should.  Your performance issues are very likely due to a lack of statistics.  pg_upgrade should have output a script to run the analyze in stages.

Comment: Thank you, @Jeremy. I just ran analyze_new_cluster.sh in the postgres user's home. I also went in via PSQL and ran VACUUM ANALYZE; Is that what you're suggesting?

Comment: Yes, I'm curious to see if that helps your performance issues.

Comment: @Jeremy, well it didn't have an immediate affect. Our CPU is still pegged at 100%.

Comment: @robhyx What's using the CPU? Assuming it's postgres processes, check the server status (or pgadmin 4 equivalent) to see what they're doing. I think it's extremely unlikely there is something inherent in 9.6 which is causing this. Possibly some background cleaning/optimising post-update?

Comment: @404 Thanks. I actually don't have PGAdmin, but it's all postgres processes from looking at the server. I have a connection pool, so there are 15 or them, all consuming 60-70% of one CPU (spread across 8). I also have every transaction that takes over a second logged. They're all queries that have never been great performance wise, but they're taking about 10 times as long as normal. Agree it's likely not something inherent in 9.6, especially since we have it running in fine in our test environment.

Comment: I wonder if it's parallel execution introduced in 9.6 which is used, but overloads your server. What is the setting for `max_parallel_workers_per_gather`?  If you set it to `0` do you still have those problems?

Comment: @robhyx Did the analyze_new_cluster.sh script finish successfully?  It can take a while to run that on a full database if it's reasonably large.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I'm not seeing a param named max_parallel_workers. I did try setting per gather to 0. Does it require a restart?

Comment: @Jeremy Yes. I also ran vacuum full analyze from within PSQL with the application accessing the DB off, and that did take a while. No affect. I feel like I'm missing something obvious since that did if for everyone else with this issue.

Comment: No restart required, only a reload of the configuration (max_parallel_workers was introduced in 10 sorry about mentioning it). But it won't affect existing connections, only new ones

Comment: Unrelated, but: what was the reason to go for 9.6 instead of 11 or 12 (which both offer even more performance enhancements then 9.6)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name we're only allowed to install from a specific repo at my customer's site, and 9.6 was the latest they had.

Comment: Ah, the stupid "repo rules" :(

Comment: I really appreciate all of this, but back to my original question, I guess there is no way to rollback the data dir, without just going back to the 9.4 one, huh? The reason I ask is, users are hammering me because they can't use the app, and I'd like to get them back up and running while I debug this on the side.

Comment: No, there's no way to downgrade the data directory.  You can only switch back to the  old, out of date, directory.